# Glimpse 1.4.2, Castle.Windsor 3.0 and custom ASP.NET MVC 3 ControllerActionInvoker

Tags: asp.net-mvc, dependency-injection, castle-windsor

I've created a custom ControllerActionInvoker as per http://ialekseev.blogspot.co.uk/2012/10/dependency-injection-in-aspnet-mvc-3.html so Castle.Windsor can resolve dependencies in my custom actions.

I've noticed however that even though I explicitly resolve the ControllerActionInvoker in my controller factory, when I use Glimpse, it isn't actually being executed:

```
public class WindsorControllerFactory : DefaultControllerFactory
    {
        private readonly IKernel kernel;

        public WindsorControllerFactory(IKernel kernel)
        {
            this.kernel = kernel;
        }

        public override void ReleaseController(IController controller)
        {
            kernel.ReleaseComponent(controller);
        }

        protected override IController GetControllerInstance(RequestContext requestContext, Type controllerType)
        {
            if (controllerType == null)
            {
                throw new HttpException(404, string.Format("The controller for path '{0}' could not be found.", requestContext.HttpContext.Request.Path));
            }

            var controller = kernel.Resolve(controllerType) as Controller;

            // Resolve new action invoker
            if (controller != null)
            {
                controller.ActionInvoker = kernel.Resolve<IActionInvoker>();
            }

            return controller;
        }
    }
```

Heres my action invoker with an extentsion method to inject properties:

```
public class WindsorActionInvoker : ControllerActionInvoker
{
    private readonly IKernel kernel;

    public WindsorActionInvoker(IKernel kernel)
    {
        this.kernel = kernel;
    }

    protected override ActionExecutedContext InvokeActionMethodWithFilters(
            ControllerContext controllerContext,
            IList<IActionFilter> filters,
            ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor,
            IDictionary<string, object> parameters)
    {
        foreach (IActionFilter actionFilter in filters)
        {
            // Extension method
            kernel.InjectProperties(actionFilter);
        }
        return base.InvokeActionMethodWithFilters(controllerContext, filters, actionDescriptor, parameters);
    }
}
```

Hence now I'm seeing object reference errors thrown in my actions for types I'm expecting Castle.Windsor inject in:

```
public class CheckCountryFilter : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public IAppSettings Settings { get; set; }
    public ILookupService LookupService { get; set; }
    public ILogger Logger { get; set; }

    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    { 
       // Logger is null!
       if (Logger.IsDebugEnabled)
```

I think that Glimpse is somehow proxying away the controller.ActionInvoker, replacing mine with its own?

**Is there away I can make Glimpse play nice with my custom ControllerActionInvoker?**

Strangely, Glimple worked on first run, but now I'm stuck with these errors!

Found a post on GitHub - https://github.com/Glimpse/Glimpse/issues/328 - that seemed to report similar issues.
By ignoring the ExecutionInspector Glimpse does work and my invoker resolves dependencies but I obviously lose at lot of useful info out of Glimpse!

**Is this my only option?**

Comment: Hello Neil, I'm not so familiar mvc3, but you could temporarily add Logger to your constructor instead of as property. This will give you an error during resolve, which might give you more information about the problem.

Comment: Hey Neil, would you mind beefing up your first code sample? I need a bit more context about how/where you replace your ActionInvoker. Glimpse should be playing nicely with your approach, just need to figure out why it isn't.

Comment: No problem - added the source for the ControllerFactory and custom invoker.

Comment: Did you manage to solve this?

Comment: Nope!  I had top go with ignoring the ExecutionInspector.